# IntelliJ source code editor shows false compilation errors

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have a problem with the following odd behaviour of the IntelliJ IDEA development environment (version 14) with scala:

After I reset the (global) scala SDK from a 2.11 version to version 2.10.4 the source code editor shows many compilation errors: list, map, print, (1 to n) etc. are all red.

The SDK is added to global libraries and the jars are all found.

However the code compiles and runs correctly (I rebuilt the project to force recompilation). Has anyone ever experienced something like this?
How can this be fixed?

I am using tha java sdk 1.7.0_55.

Comment: In file menu,  Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved the problem. If you formulate it as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @michael Please accept this as answer .. it solved my issue

Answer (score 7):

In file menu, `Invalidate Caches / Restart`

also set Incremental Type to `SBT` in `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment-> Compiler -> Scala Compiler`

Answer (score 0):

There are high chances that you didn't load your project properly, and that's why the errors are appearing. I have written a complete blog [post](https://edbinx.com/linux/solve-jetbrains-intellij-idea-false-editor-error-problem-13433.html) about how you can fix it. And following are the two methods from the write up which can correct your issue.

These two steps should be able to help you, for rest of them please check the [link](https://edbinx.com/linux/solve-jetbrains-intellij-idea-false-editor-error-problem-13433.html).

**1. Importing Project as an SBT Project:**

First of all, close your project and import it again after selecting the directory and choose SBT as an External Module. Select Import Project, then go to the project directory, select your project, choose Import Project from external model, opt for SBT and click Next and then Finish. IntelliJ IDEA will ask you to overwrite the .idea file, say Yes to it. After IDEA is done indexing and loading your project, all the issues will be sorted out. The editor will work fine, and you will have your missing features restored.

**2.  Fixing missing project files with SBT-IDEA:**

Sometimes IntelliJ IDEA misses out on the most important project files and shows editor errors along with a broken code completion, however, during the code compilation, everything works as per your expectation. This solution works with a plugin called as SBT-IDEA. Now to enable this plugin, open your terminal and follow the instruction:

a. Create a file plugins.sbt in the directory `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins`

b. Now, write the following content to it:

```
resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.7.0-SNAPSHOT")
```

Note: Please check for the latest version at the plugin’s GitHub [page](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea).

Save and quit, and execute `sudo sbt gen-idea` in your project root directory.

I hope it helps!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I changed build.sbt file (added empty line and saved file). Then I Idea re-checked dependencies and indexed. Then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all the false errors sometimes you need to disable type-aware highlighting

- by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> for example:

https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2011/03/02/type-aware-highlighting/

The errors seem to be caused because Scala plugin re-implements compiler logic and that is imperfect.

More information here in the comments:

https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/5pcwfv/question_what_causes_intellij_idea_highlighter/

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when IntelliJ tries to build your code by itself and fails miserably.

If you know your build is successful, all you need to do is edit the Run Configuration and remove the Build part inside the Before Launch part.

This solution solved it for me!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30856173)

Answer (score 0):

Try invalidating your caches and restarting IDEA.

> (File > Invalidate Cache)

Wait for IDEA to re-index your project (Status indicator on lower right status bar). The caches will sometimes become corrupted. This is most likely to occur upon reorganizing a project as you mentioned you did.